# Array.filter is not returning the expected output

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a nested array of data. I am able to get the first set of data based on my condition, but when I apply `Array.filter` on this result set, it is not giving me the expected result.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "Date": "02/04/2019",
      "Total": "1000",
      "Success": "850",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [
        {
          "name": "Reason1",
          "Count": 2,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Reason2",
          "Count": 6,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Date": "03/04/2019",
      "Total": "800",
      "Success": "750",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [
        {
          "name": "Reason1",
          "Count": 3,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Reason2",
          "Count": 1,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

First I have applied the below `Array.filter` to get the FailureDetails based on date:

```
var filtered = data
          .filter(value => value.Date == "02/04/2019")
          .map(e => e.FailureDeatils);
```

This will result in the following output:

```
FailureDeatils:[{"name":"Reason1","Count":2,"Description":[{"DescriptionID": "01","Status": "Failure Point1"},{"DescriptionID": "01","Status": "Failure Point1"}]},{"name":"Reason2","Count":6,"Description":[{"DescriptionID": "01","Status": "Failure Point1"},{"DescriptionID": "01","Status": "Failure Point1"}]}]
```

Now based on Reason, i.e. Reason1 or Reason 2, I want to get the description. But when I apply `Array.filter` on that, it is returning the output as undefined.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to filter the results on the second filter ?

Comment: This is the one I have tried:var filtered2 = filtered
      .filter(value => value.name == "Reason1")
      .map(e => e.Description);
      console.log("Filtered Data2",filtered2 )

Comment: but here value.name only is coming as undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would apply filter on the filtered array to get the result, however since it will be an array of array you would need to map over the filtered array before filtering it too.

However you could simply use reducer to flatten the initial FailureDescription array instead of mapping it.

```js
var data = [
    {
      "Date": "02/04/2019",
      "Total": "1000",
      "Success": "850",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [
        {
          "name": "Reason1",
          "Count": 2,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Reason2",
          "Count": 6,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Date": "03/04/2019",
      "Total": "800",
      "Success": "750",
      "Failure": "150",
      "FailureDeatils": [
        {
          "name": "Reason1",
          "Count": 3,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Reason2",
          "Count": 1,
          "Description": [
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            },
            {
              "DescriptionID": "01",
              "Status": "Failure Point1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

var filtered = data
          .filter(value => value.Date == "02/04/2019")
          .reduce((acc,e) => acc.concat(e.FailureDeatils), []);
          
const reason = "Reason1";


var res = filtered.filter((data) => data.name == reason).reduce((acc, item) =>{
    acc = acc.concat(item.Description);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```